# POST request 403 forbidden is not supported

Tags: android, json, rest, android-annotations

i am currently trying to get response JSON by doing a REST request , but problem is "When Status is 200:OK then i get JSON response but when status is 403:Forbidden then i am unable to get JSON response". Following is my working code on 200:OK but not on any other status message:

**Interface:**

```
@Rest(rootUrl = "http://something.com", converters = {FormHttpMessageConverter.class, GsonHttpMessageConverter.class})
public interface RestClient {
    @Post("/isec/api/user/login")
    JsonObject LoginIt(@Field String email, @Field String password, @Field String type);
}
```

**Usage:**

```
JsonObject p = restClient.LoginIt(emailText.getText().toString(),passwordText.getText().toString(),spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().toUpperCase());
            GsonStr = new Gson().toJson(p);
            ShowResults(p);
```

**Log:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-1-thread-1
                  Process: com.jutt.isec, PID: 3463
                  org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 Forbidden
                      at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:88)
                      at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:585)
                      at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:541)
                      at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:499)
                      at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:447)
                      at com.jutt.isec.RestClient_.LoginIt(RestClient_.java:41)
                      at com.jutt.isec.MainActivity.doLogin(MainActivity.java:130)
                      at com.jutt.isec.MainActivity_.access$201(MainActivity_.java:31)
                      at com.jutt.isec.MainActivity_$5.execute(MainActivity_.java:159)
                      at org.androidannotations.api.BackgroundExecutor$Task.run(BackgroundExecutor.java:405)
                      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Any Suggestions , or solutions ? thanks in advance

Comment: If you get a 403 forbidden then you will not get a json response to begin with. So dont try to handle it as json.

Comment: then how am i supposed to handle this in exception or something , otherwise my application is crashing anyway

Comment: Put the call in a try catch block. Then your application will not crash. If your application is crashing you will find the cause in the LogCat. So you know which exception is thrown. Tell us which exception you have.

Comment: Is http://www.solve5.com your own service? You could change server implementation so that it returns all API responses as JSON. You would still obviously need to handle the Unauthorized -JSON, but it would be more consistent API.

Comment: `org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException`

Comment: yes it is my own server @mpartan and it is returning JSON as response i think , greenapps i have tried catching exception and it worked but it is not good way to handle this problem i think ?

Comment: I think it's adequate. Anything you need more?

Answer (score 0):

You don't receive a json, but you can check the status that you receive.
You should use a RestErrorHandler, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Rest-API)

An example of my code

```
@EBean
public class RestErrorHandler implements RestErrorHandler {

    @RootContext
    Context context;

    @Bean
    MyErrorHandler mErrorHandler;

    @Bean
    OttoBus ottoBus;

    @Override
    public void onRestClientExceptionThrown(NestedRuntimeException e) {

        if (e instanceof HttpStatusCodeException) {
            HttpStatusCodeException exception = (HttpStatusCodeException) e;
            if (exception.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED) {
        mErrorHandler.handleGenericError(context.getString(R.string.auth_error));
            } else {
                mErrorHandler.handleGenericError(context.getString(R.string.generic_error));
            }
        } else if (e instanceof RestClientException) {
            // do something else
        } else {
            mErrorHandler.handleGenericError(context.getString(R.string.root_error));
            Log.e("errorw", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Your RestClient must extend RestClientErrorHandling like this

```
public interface RestClient extends RestClientErrorHandling
```

Then, where you instantiate your RestClient, you should set your RestErrorHandler as this below:

```
@AfterInject
public void init() {
    mService.setRestErrorHandler(mErrorHandler);
}
```

You can change HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED with HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN